# DXGF model not showing in the scene

Tags: three.js

3D model is not displaying

Loading DXF model with dxf loader from GIT. Model is not displaying, only black screen is showing. It might be the camera, the model problem or any other problem. I am loading preprepared model. Im a newby in Three.js

```
        <div id="webgl-output"></div>
        <script>

            function init() {


                // Loading DXF loader
                let loader = new THREE.DXFLoader();


                loader.load('./disegni/BAPAEA065BEAA-00^SAGOMA.dxf', function(data) {
                    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 2000);
                    var render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    camera.position.set(0, 0, 53);

                    render.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas = render.domElement);

                    render.setClearColor(0x111111, 1);
                    // renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000))
                    // renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

                    var sceneGroup = data



                    sceneGroup.rotation.z = 0.5 * Math.PI;
                    // sceneGroup.scale.set(1, 1, 1)

                    scene.add(data);

                    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(180, window.innerWidth/ window.innerHeight, 500, 1000, 100)


                    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0)


                    sceneGroup.traverse(function(child) {
                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        child.material.color = 0xffb830;
                    }enter code here
                });

                    sceneGroup.position.set(0, 0, -53);
                    scene.add(sceneGroup);
                    window.sceneGroup = sceneGroup;



                    document.getElementById("webgl-output").appendChild(render.domElement)
                    render.render(scene, camera); 

                });

            }


            (function() {
                init()
            })()



        </script>
```

Thank you for any help that might assist me in displaying the 3D graphics